# Vector of objects with identification numbers and connections

Tags: c++, object, vector

i'm trying to do that:

I would like to have a vector (std::vector) with object defined like this:

```
class MyObj{
   private:
       idNumber= // it could be a pointer
       firstConnection= // it could be a pointer
       secondConnection= // it could be a pointer
   public:
   ...
};

vector<MyObj> vectorOfObj(10);
```

So I want the `idNumber` of the object, which is an element of vector, corresponding with the index of the same element, and set the connections (bidirectional) between the elements (in example `vectorOfObj[5]` is connected with `vectorOfObj[7]` and `vectorOfObj[4]`) I'd like the elements keep their references valid (id & connections) if the structure of the vector is modified (in example if element 6 is set in 4 and 4 is set in 6, the objects change their id and if 5 was connected with 4 now is connected with 6 ). I accept all kind of solutions if they worth it. I thought a lot about it but I cannot find a solution.

I hope I was clear. Thankyou!

Comment: Could one object be connected to several other objects ? Do you need to have bidirectional references( 5 -> 7, 7 -> 5) or only in one direction (5 -> 7)?

Comment: Bidirectional references, and yes one object could be connected with several ebjects!

Comment: Your constraints are too tight and your requirements too brief. You will _not_ be able to store valid pointers or iterators to elements for a vector (unless you guarantee that the vector will never grow thereafter) and I would not recommend even attempting to do so. You can't store an index? Or some _other_ kind of unique index? Then use a map instead of a vector? All quite fishy...

Comment: Yes. It's possible to use a map, I'm not an expert, so all advise are good for me! Sorry for the fishy problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
map<yourcommonthing, vector<MyObj>> yourMap;
```

So that what are all the MyObj that have common things you can group by that which is also the key of map.

If idNumber is the common among one or more MyObj then,

```
map<idNumber, vector<MyObj>> vectorOfObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description tells me that you are probably looking for a graph representation.

You could use Boost Graph here:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5dc4d738aaba65d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp> // make_iterator_range
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // for std::setw

using namespace boost;

struct MyObj{
    int idNumber;
};

typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, MyObj> Graph;

int main() {
    Graph g;

    Graph::vertex_descriptor // essentially, index into the vector of MyObj
        node1 = add_vertex(MyObj {42}, g),
        node2 = add_vertex(MyObj { 7},  g),
        node3 = add_vertex(MyObj {99}, g),
        node4 = add_vertex(MyObj {-1}, g);

    std::cout << "node1: " << node1 << "\n"; // 0
    std::cout << "node2: " << node2 << "\n"; // 1
    std::cout << "node3: " << node3 << "\n"; // 2
    std::cout << "node4: " << node4 << "\n"; // 3

    add_edge(node1, node3, g);
    add_edge(node2, node3, g);
    add_edge(node4, node1, g);

    // now we have a graph with these connections:
    for(auto const& connection: make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
    {
        Graph::vertex_descriptor sd = source(connection, g);
        Graph::vertex_descriptor td = target(connection, g);
        MyObj const& s = g[sd];
        MyObj const& t = g[td];

        std::cout << "Connection of " << sd << " (idNumber=" << std::setw(2) << s.idNumber << ") <-> "
                                      << td << " (idNumber=" << std::setw(2) << t.idNumber << ")\n";
    }

}
```

Output:

```
node1: 0
node2: 1
node3: 2
node4: 3
Connection of 0 (idNumber=42) <-> 2 (idNumber=99)
Connection of 1 (idNumber= 7) <-> 2 (idNumber=99)
Connection of 3 (idNumber=-1) <-> 0 (idNumber=42)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a regular [Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)). 
There are 2 main ways you can store your referenses:

- List of all edjes in separate vector
- [Adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)

The simpliest solution on my opinion it is to use list of edjes,

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> connections;
```

and each time you want to find connected points you have to go through entire list of all connections.
if you have a lot of connections (thouthands and more) you may speed it up by using

```
std::multimap<int, int> conncections
.....
// to find all connected points:
std::pair <std::multimap<int,int>::iterator, std::multimap<int,int>::iterator> ret;
ret = conncections.equal_range(ch);
```